# Matrix Induction proofs using $\rm mod$.

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, induction

Please could someone advise me on where to even start with this question.  Thanks in advance

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, for some $n\geqslant 1$. Given any prime number $p\gt1$, write $A_p$ for the matrix you get by replacing each entry in $A$ with its value ${\rm mod}\, p.$ For example, 
$$\pmatrix{
1 & 27 & 11 \\
2 & 10 & -3 \\
0 & -4 & 17 
}_3
=
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 
}$$
Define an operator $\odot_p$ ("matrix multiplication ${\rm mod}\,p\,$") by $A\odot_pB=(AB)_p.$ For example, $$\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
}\odot_3
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1
}=\pmatrix{
1 & 4 & 4 \\
4 & 1 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 1
}_3=\pmatrix{
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
}$$
We'll say that $A$ is *invertible-mod-p* provided there exists some matrix $B$ such that $$A\odot_p B= B\odot_p A = I$$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

$a) \quad$ Prove by induction on $n\geqslant1$ that $|A_p|\equiv |A|\mod p$. 
 
 $b)\quad$ Using the result stated in $(a)$, prove that $A_p$ is invertible-mod-$p$ *if and only if* $|A|$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Well, you can start by the base case. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, i proved that when n = 1, i.e a 1 x 1 matrix. Im not sure if i have to make up some matrix A. Anyways, if i say i have a matrix:

A = (4) and p = 3

Then Ap = (1)
the determinant is = |Ap| = 1

So 1 = 4 mod 3 is true as 1/3 leaves remainder 1 and 4/3 leaves remainder 1.  Thats literally as far as i can get.

Comment: Do you know how to express the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix in terms of determinants of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices?

Comment: Hi Gerry, no i am afraid i do not.

Comment: Then what do you know about determinants? How would you evaluate the determinant of, say, a $4\times4$ matrix?

Comment: I've seen where you have clarified that you do know about going from $n-1$ to $n$. So: prove the congruence for $n=1$; then assume it's true for $n\times n$ matrices; then express the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ determinant in terms of $n\times n$ determinants, apply the induction hypothesis, and you should have your solution.

Comment: Making any progress, Hayley?

Comment: Hayley, I see by your deleted answer that you think you understand now. In that case, let me encourage you to write up and post an answer to your question. This is encouraged on this site.